# Checking the same values in two different columns of same table and then compare in sql

Tags: sql

```
cid       ctypeid  tid   check   asscid      ci
19149     6        2     0      NULL         0
253440    1        1     0      22297922     1
1361285   5        2     0      NULL         1
22297922  2        1     1      NULL         NULL
49821961  5        1     0      NULL         1
```

I have to check whether `asscid` i.e `22297922` is in the cid column which is there actually.
So I have to compare when the `asscid` is in the cid and then get the value of `ci` in case of `asscid` (where `cid` is `253440`)which is 1 in this case and then assign the same value 1 of `ci` to `cid` column `22297922` which is `null` in this case.

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: Is it recursive by nature? Or just one pass is enough? What I am trying to ask is if a record's "ci" is updated during the first pass, should we update  the rows referring to this.

Comment: sql is the database

Comment: simply whenever there is some value in asscid first i have to check whether that value is in  cid and then assign the value of ci of asscid to the cid.We only have to update the value of ci for that column else will remain the same.......

Comment: SQL is a query language, not the name of a specific database product. All relational databases are "SQL databases". So again: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use an update with a self join.

Select:

```
SELECT t.asscid, t2.cid, t.ci, t2.ci --We will next update t2.ci with t.ci
FROM table t
JOIN table t2 on t.asscid = t2.cid
```

Update:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.ci = t.ci
FROM table t
JOIN table t2 on t.asscid = t2.cid
```

Update with condition: (So that only rows that have different `ci` are updated)

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.ci = t.ci
FROM table t
JOIN table t2 on t.asscid = t2.cid
              and t.ci <> t2.ci
```

Comment: @Ritesh The select is there just to make sure it's correct with your logic.  Always a good idea to select first, then change to the update when happy with the results.

Comment: @Aaron--I also want to add some if exists condition because once the value of ci is changed then again i dont want to update it again.Else without the condition the update statement will execeute again and again .Do u got my point?

Comment: @Ritesh I believe I understand your concern, but it will only run once for each match, it won't loop.  That said, right now the condition is `t.asscid = t2.cid`, so it will only update the `ci` in the corresponding `cid` row, to what the `ci` is in the corresponding `asscid` row.  Do it need to be more specific than that?

Comment: @Ritesh Wait, I think I follow.  I'll edit in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Select Assid from emp A
Where exists ( select 1 from Emp B where a.assid=b.Cis )